# ‘find’ vs ‘find out’

Tags: word-usage

> Mary and her husband Dimitri lived in the tiny village of Perachora in southern Greece. One of Mary's prize possessions was a little white lamb which her husband had given her. She kept it tied to a tree in a field during the day and went to fetch it every evening. One evening, however, the lamb was missing. The rope had been cut, so it was obvious that the lamb had been stolen.

> When Dimitri came in from the fields, his wife told him what had happened. Dimitri at once set out to **find** the thief. He knew it would not prove difficult in such a small village. After telling several of his friends about the theft, Dimitri **found out** that his neighbour, Aleko, had suddenly acquired a new lamb. Dimitri immediately went to Aleko's house and angrily accused him of stealing the lamb. He told him he had better return it or he would call the police. Aleko denied taking it and led Dimitri into his back-yard. It was true that he had just bought a lamb, he explained, but his lamb was black. Ashamed of having acted so rashly, Dimitri apologized to Aleko for having accused him. While they were talking it began to rain and Dimitri stayed in Aleko's house until the rain stopped. When he went outside half an hour later, he was astonished to **find** that the little black lamb was almost white. Its wool, which had been dyed black, had been washed clean by the rain!

Sometimes use **find**, sometime use **find out**, even if it is followed by **that**.

What is the difference between them？

Answer (score 1):

There is overlap between the uses, but in the example you've given, "find" refers to locating a person. It could also be used for a physical object, or an abstract thing, such as a path, a method, or a way.

In contrast, "find out [that]" refers to gaining information about something. The word "that" introduces a subordinate clause detailing the information about the neighbor that was discovered.

It is also possible to use "find that", followed by a subordinate clause, to show that some abstract thing was discovered or deemed to be true:
"The judge found that the evidence was inadmissible."

Comment: Can I replace **find that** with **find out that**？

Comment: Sometime you can, sometimes not. Check the Merriam-Webster dictionary definitions for "find" and "find out". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find  and https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find out